# GoogleTrans: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Tags: python, translation, google-translate, googletrans

I'm looking into a bunch of different libraries to learn python a little better and I want to try to make a program with the GoogleTrans library. I downloaded it using pip then imported it and read how to use it. I can copy line by line but it will still give me an error. Here is my code, what am I doing to get this

```
from googletrans import Translator

translator = Translator()
translateText = translator.translate("hola.")
```

Here's the error I am getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\SteelZK\Desktop\Projects\gtts-translator.py", line 4, in <module>
    translateText = translator.translate("hola.")
  File "C:\Users\SteelZK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\googletrans\client.py", line 172, in translate
    data = self._translate(text, dest, src)
  File "C:\Users\SteelZK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\googletrans\client.py", line 75, in _translate
    token = self.token_acquirer.do(text)
  File "C:\Users\SteelZK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\googletrans\gtoken.py", line 180, in do
    self._update()
  File "C:\Users\SteelZK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\googletrans\gtoken.py", line 59, in _update
    code = unicode(self.RE_TKK.search(r.text).group(1)).replace('var ', '')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

Comment: Check the module for issues: https://github.com/ssut/py-googletrans/issues/88

Comment: The error means that the result of `.search()` is `None`.

Answer (score 0):

fixed libraries should be here I am testing them now

https://pypi.org/project/py-translator/

Install like

```
pip3 install py_translator==1.8.9
```

and code

```
from py_translator import Translator
s = Translator().translate(text='Hello my friend', dest='es').text
print(s)
```